# How can I find indexes of rows in which columns are equal to NaN?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to get indexes in which NaN is present in the "balance" column. I have tried many ways, also in the documentation I have not found how to use == to compare with NaN.

code for create df:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'user' : ['Ivan', 'Petr', 'Nikolay', 'Andrey'], 
        'time_per_page' :  [10, 30 , 15, 5], 
        'pages' : [7, 9, 12, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4'])
df['balance'] = pd.Series([200, 150], index=['user3', 'user4'])
df
```

[my DataFrame - picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tvf1.jpg)

Frome some themes of stackoverflow i find this way:
`df = (df > 0).reindex (list (range (5)))`
not work

I found boolean values of is null by timing, but did not find a way to output indexes where there is True

`df1 = df.isnull() df3 = df1['balance'] == True df3`

Answer (score 1):

You can index your DataFrame's index with the boolean mask you obtain from checking where your column is NaN:

```
out = df.index[df["balance"].isna()]
```

out:

```
Index(['user1', 'user2'], dtype='object')
```